# Django Social Auth Debug HTTP Error 400: Bad Request (linkedin)

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I've been using Django Social Auth and I've been able to login using both Facebook and Twitter. But I've been getting a HTTP 400 error when I tried it with linkedin. I've been getting the following error:

Sorry but some error made you impossible to login.

HTTP Error 400: Bad Request (linkedin)

Any ideas how to debug this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It works on localhost but not when deployed.

Comment: Do you get any more information when you Debug = True?

Comment: No, no additional information

Comment: Can you clarify which view is generating this response? Is this happening when you go to the LinkedIn website to login/authenticate?

Comment: Yes, it does not take me to the LinkedIn website but rather it gives me the 400

Comment: I have the same error.  It only occurs on production.

Answer (score 1):

Quite old question, but I got the chance to debug this issue today and the error was cause by server datetime mismatch with current UTC value, updating the server date fixed the LinkedIn issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd debug this capturing the network traffic and looking what is wrong in the request. You can use for example Wireshark to capture and browse it. This will at least give you idea which part of OAuth process is failing.